# Besides the Hebrews, were there any other ancient cults that used salt in animal sacrifices?

Tags: religion, religious-history, bible, animals

The Hebrew Bible (Leviticus 2:13) stipulates that all animal sacrifices must have salt. I was wondering if we find such a phenomenon of requiring salt in the cultic rituals of any other society in history.

Answer (score 8):

"Any other society in history" is a bit broad of a term to search for, but thus also easily found, when asking for example Pliny:

> In ancient Roman religion, mola salsa ("salted flour") was a mixture of coarse-ground, toasted emmer flour and salt prepared by the Vestal Virgins and used in every official sacrifice.
>
> — [WP: Mola salsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mola_salsa)

More on that [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/53629/26786).

Comment: Really good catch.